# How to assign the result of a SELECT query to java object in mybatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

I am trying to insert a list of authors into Author table in mybatis mapper xml using foreach loop as below,

AuthorVO.java

```
class AuthorVO {
private List<Author> authors;
...
}
```

Author.java

```
class Author{
private int id;
private String name;
private String level;
....
}
```

Author.xml

```
<insert id="insertAuthor(authorVO)">
<foreach item="author" index="index" collection="authors">

INSERT into Author (id, name, level)
values
(
(select id from get_next_id where table_name="Author"),
#{author.name},
#{author.level}
)
</insert>

<!-- Need to copy the id value into the author object (author.id) -->

</foreach>
```

Here I am getting the primary key (id) for Author table from get_next_id table.

Now I need to update author.id with the primary key value.
Something like:

```
#{author.id} = (select id from get_next_id where table_name="Author")
```

Please let me know the syntax or correct way of copying the id value from the table into the java pojo object (Author.id)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using selectKey without foreach and looping thru collection in your java code instead:

```
<insert id="insertAuthor(authorVO)">
    <selectKey keyProperty="author.id" keyColumn="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
        select id from get_next_id where table_name="Author"
    </selectKey>

    INSERT into Author (id, name, level)
    values
    (
         #{author.id},
         #{author.name},
         #{author.level}
    )
</insert>
```

Comment: <selectkey> is not supported inside the<foreach>.         Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.  I have updated my answer to suggest you iterate over your collection in java to call the insert multiple times instead of using foreach which seems designed to build the sql statement not execute a statement multiple times